# In a $16\times16$ chessboard, what is the probability that a rectangle chosen at random on the chess board is a square?

Tags: probability

In a $16\times16$ chessboard, what is the probability that a rectangle chosen at random on the chess board is a square?

1. $\dfrac{3}{126}$
2. $\dfrac{1}{136}$
3. $\dfrac{1}{68}$
4. $\dfrac{3}{68}$
5. $\dfrac{11}{136}$

Comment: How many rectangles are there? How many squares?

Comment: i thought 1496/16! which must be simplified

Comment: What is this cat you're solving problems for?

Answer (score 5):

To count the squares in the chessboard: there is clearly only one $16\times16$ square.  If you imagine a $15\times15$ square in the top left corner, it can be shifted to two positions (including the original) horizontally, and two positions vertically, so there are four options.  Continuing in this way, the total number of squares is
$$1^2+2^2+\cdots+16^2\ .$$
To count the rectangles, consider the chessboard not as consisting of $16\times16$ squares, but of $17\times17$ lines.  To choose a rectangle we must choose two different horizontal lines to form its upper and lower edges, and two different vertical lines to form its left and right edges.  So the number of rectangles is $C(17,2)^2$, and the required probability is
$$\frac{1^2+2^2+\cdots+16^2}{C(17,2)^2}=\frac{16\times17\times33}{6}\frac{2^2}{17^2\times16^2}=\frac{11}{136}\ .$$